# Duplicate context menu icons when launching the app from background

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, contextmenu

I am testing my app with "Don't Keep Activities"  options  from developer options. When I try to background the app and launch it , am getting multiple duplicate icons added to the actionbar.[image]

I am adding the context menu icon from the fragment. I have a string passed in a bundle to the fragment. When I background and launch the app, Android tries to recreate the activity and  as **setHasOptionsMenu(true);** is called multiple time during this process and adds duplicate icons to the actionbar.

The following fixes this issue , but would like to know if this is the best approach

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm a little late to answer your question, but it can be useful for future users.

**The problem origin**:

When you background the app and and launch it, the system will save and restore the state of your fragment. Also `onCreate()` method will be called and a new fragment will be added to your Activity, and you end up with multiple fragments running in your activity, each one added an item to the menu.

**The solution**:

(+) The *correct fix*: simply add a null check in your `onCreate()` method before adding your fragment (to avoid duplication)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = ...
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }
```

---

(+) Or a *workaround1*: Clear your `menu` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method of your fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

---

(+) Or a *workaround2*: Call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` only when `savedInstanceState == null` like you mentioned in OP.